# Error in rownames replacement has length zero

Tags: json, r

I am importing data from an API that returns `JSON`:

```
substringNotificationData <<- sub('^[^\\{]*\\{', '{', notificationsData)
notificationsDT <<- jsonlite::fromJSON(paste(readLines(textConnection(substringNotificationData),warn="false"), collapse=""))
notificationsbinded <<- do.call(rbind, notificationsDT)
notificationsDataTable<<- notificationsbinded$notifications
```

This is what my code in `R` looks like.

However, I keep getting:

> Error in rownames(value[[jj]])[ri] <- rownames(xij) :
>   replacement has length zero at the step when I am rbinding.

How do I resolve this?

Sample data:

```
  {"total_count":855,"offset":0,"limit":50,"notifications":[{"adm_big_picture":"","adm_group":"","adm_group_message":{"en":""},"adm_large_icon":"","adm_small_icon":"","adm_sound":"","spoken_text":{},"alexa_ssml":null,"alexa_display_title":null,"amazon_background_data":false,"android_accent_color":"","android_group":"","android_group_message":{"en":""},"android_led_color":"","android_sound":"","android_visibility":1,"app_id":"33fbf42c-de58-4c33-a92a-f74d82d6c619","big_picture":"https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/emailerimages/11122017/PushBanner_Happy40_12122017_V1.jpg","buttons":null,"canceled":false,"chrome_big_picture":"","chrome_icon":"","chrome_web_icon":"","chrome_web_image":"","chrome_web_badge":"","content_available":false,"contents":{"en":"Use code HAPPY40 on these \u0026 get the best at your doorstep."},"converted":43,"data":{"custom":"{ \"aps\": { \"alert\": \" Sunday Special: Extra 40% Off! Use code HAPPY40 on these \u0026 get the best at your doorstep.\", \"sound \": \"default\", \"pushType\": \"productlist\", \"categoryid\": \"638\", \"categoryname\": \"Collection\", \"parentid\": \"2\", \"filter\": {\"OrderBy\":\"position\"} } }"},"delayed_option":"immediate","delivery_time_of_day":"9:28PM","errored":1,"excluded_segments":[],"failed":101,"firefox_icon":"","headings":{"en":" Sunday Special: Extra 40% Off!"},"id":"b19a67e9-630c-4377-928d-348a33dbcef4","include_player_ids":null,"included_segments":["All"],"ios_badgeCount":1,"ios_badgeType":"None","ios_category":"","ios_sound":"","isAdm":false,"isAndroid":true,"isChrome":false,"isChromeWeb":false,"isAlexa":false,"isFirefox":false,"isIos":false,"isSafari":false,"isWP":false,"isWP_WNS":false,"large_icon":"","priority":5,"queued_at":1515341005,"remaining":193192,"send_after":1515342600,"small_icon":"appicon_sil","successful":70898,"tags":null,"filters":null,"template_id":null,"ttl":null,"url":"","web_buttons":null,"web_push_topic":null,"wp_sound":"","wp_wns_sound":""}]}
```

Comment: is there any sample data we can use to replicate the issue?

Comment: @Sixiang.Hu: Added. Have a look please